# Excessive Use of jQuery's preventDefault() and stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was recently in a discussion with a work colleague about some differences in our coding practices, where I raised an issue about his excessive use of the two above mentioned methods in his event handlers. Specifically, they **all** look like this...

```
$('span.whatever').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    /* do things */

});
```

He has made the claim that this is a good practice with no foreseeable blowback, and will improve cross-platform support while reducing unexpected issues down the road.

My question to you guys: If he's right, why hasn't the jQuery team implemented this behavior globally applied to all event handlers? In effect, my assumption is that he's wrong simply because the methods are available for independent use, but who knows... Your insight is much appreciated.

--

**Update:** I did a simple speed test, and there is a little drag caused by these two function, but nothing terribly noticeable. Still, among other things, a good reason to be deliberate in their use I think.

```
$('span.whatever').on('click', function(e) {

    var start = new Date();

    for (i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    console.log( new Date() - start );

});
```

The above logged ~9.5 seconds as is, and ~2.5 seconds when I took the function calls out of the loop.

Comment: If he's calling *both* he should just use `return false;` for brevity. Incidentally, while I'm *interested* in the answer, this question can only lead to speculation/discussion. So, I'm sorry, but I'm voting to close as 'non-constructive'.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's good practice. It's unnecessary if you don't need those methods.

Comment: @DavidThomas If SO's not the right place for this, my apologies. Perhaps it belongs on Code Review?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where it belongs; [codereview.se] isn't the place (that's for reviewing working code to improve its performance/function, though check out their [faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) to be sure). Perhaps [programmers.se]? But I'd suggest asking on [meta], to be sure (including a link to this question).

Comment: @65Fbef05 If he included both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` then he should be using `return false;` at the end of his function. That way you don't have to excessively access the `event` object to invoke both methods. The `return false` would just eat up the event and that'll be the end of it :)

Comment: Good to know @sweetamylase, I'll do some performance testing to see if there's any actual drag in his practice.

Comment: What default behavior does a SPAN have anyway? ;)

Comment: @landons That's what I said! lol

Comment: If anything, this could *break* other functionality, such as another script's proxying events.  I would keep pushing back on him to only stop propagation when there's a specific reason to do so.

Comment: Just to note: just because a click handler is on a <span> tag, doesn't mean that tag is the origin of the event. You could have one or more child <a> tags in there, and decide to trap the events at bubbling time, rather than on each tag explicitly.

Comment: @65Fbef05: I don't think your updated test is very representative: it tests 2 function calls versus nothing, which of course will tell you that nothing is faster.

I think a better way to test this would be to create 3 versions of your handler: one with nothing; one with the 2 explicit event manipulation calls; and one with a return false. What you should loop on is triggering the event for all 3 cases "$('span.whatever').trigger('click');" . Note that depending on the depth of the tag, the event bubbling cycle would change too (and bubbling would stop both with the calls and return false)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't do the same thing as your colleague (pushing the 2 calls on EVERY event handler), but I do have the same practice of using these calls explicitely rather than a "return false;", and I believe that has made my life easier.

When I started with Jquery, I figured if I need to both stop propagation, and prevent default, I should just "return false", which I kind of did all over the place.

```
$('a.whatever').on('click', function(e) {

    do_stuff();

    return false;
});
```

But there was 2 problems I enventually encountered:

- if do_stuff() has any critical error causing an exception, "return false;" will never be reached!!! The error will eventually be "nicely" swallowed by jquery; your event will bubble, and let the browser execute the default action. If you are in a single page app and a link was clicked, for all you know the page navigated away, and the entire app state went down the toilet (I've been there before).
- I was too lenient with my return false: in many cases, I just needed a preventdefault(). "return false" was killing event bubbling and sometimes hindered my ability to perform another action higher up the dom hierarchy (or made some other plugin/libs I was using not work properly)

So I now prefer to be explicit. I litterally **never** use "return false;" any more. If I have an event handler that must either not propagate or not execute default, I deliberatly put that in my function **FIRST**, before any processing code. Whatever happens during event handling should **NOT** affect the fact that I do NOT want the default action to run, and/or event to not bubble.

And yes, that being said, I am also mindful of using just one of the 2 when required (or none at all in some cases). I do not just add both preventDefault() and stopPropagation() for no reason. Everywhere I manipulate an event in a handler, it is part of a conscious case-by-case decision.

Comment: I have just completely agreed with your answer even though I haven't been in that situation, your argument seems complete and experienced.

Comment: Solid rational, and I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a problem if the element is part of a menu and the click event was supposed to bubble out and tell the menu to close itself too.

Or if a menu was open elsewhere and clicking outside the menu was supposed to bubble up to the body where an event handler would close the menu. But the element having stopped the bubble, prevents the menu from closing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">header
              <div id="footer">footer
              <div id="content">click this!!!</div>
              </div>
            </div>


        </div>


$("#wrapper div").click(function(){
  console.log(  $(this) )
});
```

Please try clicked to div and show console...

And now added

```
$("#wrapper div").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```